# Setting a Protobuf Submessage or Embeded Message and return the Message Object

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I run into a Segfault when using protocol-buffers with submessages. I can't post all my code so I try to give an example.

The .proto code is something like this:

```
Message {
    optional int id = 1;
    optional SubMessage submsg = 2;
}

SubMessage {
    optional int foo = 1;
}
```

In the C++ code I have a function which creates and returns a SubMessage to an other function which embeds the SubMessage into a Message and returns that one to an other function,...

```
SubMessage createSubMessage() {
    SubMessage smsg;
    smsg.set_foo(12);
    return smsg;
}

Message createMessage() {
    Message msg;
    // with this line i get the segfault, without not
    SubMessage* smsg = msg.mutable_submsg();
    // I get the segfault no matter if i actually
    // set the submessage or not. 
    // smsg.CopyFrom(createSubMessage();
    return msg;
}

void foo() {
    for(;;) {
        Message msg;
        msg = createMessage();
   }
}
```

And the error I am getting is coming from SubMessage::MergeFrom()

```
[libprotobuf FATAL messges_pb.cc:1128] CHECK failed: (&from) != (this): 
Segmentation fault
```

The Segfault interestingly appears in the second iteration of the loop, at the second assignment to msg.

I already tried a lot of fuzzing, allocating a SubMessage on the heap and setting it with set_allocated_submsg(), CopyFrom(), MergeFrom(), copy constructors and so on,... I am still running into the same problem.

Comment: I don't think your example code actually demonstrates the problem -- I see no reason why it should give the error you quoted. I suspect that the real problem exists only in your real code and not the example. Could you try to create a complete, self-contained example program that we can actually compile (e.g. including a `main()` function) which shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your var msg in the function createMessage() is destroyed and disallocated after the return of the function.

You should try to use msg as an attribut of your main class.

Comment: No. As written, the code is fine, because it is returning the objects by value (not reference or pointer). Returning by value will be slow because the whole message will need to be copied, but it shouldn't crash.